# Show the error message

Tags: odoo, openerp-8

how to show the error message "The room was  already booked" . i  want to check by ** room_id,** start** , how it is possible?

> py file

```
 _columns = {
    'room_id' : fields.many2one('room.management', string="Room Booking"),
    'duration': fields.integer('Duration'),
    'reason': fields.char('Reason',requierd=True ,help="short deatails about booking"),
    'start': fields.datetime('Start At',requierd=True),
    'end': fields.datetime('End At',requierd=True),
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`constrains`](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html#openerp.api.constrains) method decorator:

```
@api.one
@api.constrains('start', 'end', 'room_id')
def _check_room_overlap(self):
    overlaping_bookings = self.search_count([
        ('room_id', '=', self.room_id.id),
        ('start', '<', self.end),
        ('end', '>', self.start),
    ])
    if overlaping_bookings:
        raise exceptions.ValidationError("The room was already booked")
```

Comment: Thanks Ludwik, its working but i cant able to book that room after the date the same error arises.Like this " Validate error, error while validate constrains , invalid value room.management(2) in domain term('room_id', '=', room.room.management(2))"

Comment: I edited my posts (changed `self.room_id` to `self.room_id.id`, which should return the actual numeric value). It should work now.

Comment: one Error global name exceptions not defined.

Comment: You need to import them first. `from openerp import exceptions`.

Comment: thanks a lot, i was done whatever you told me, and right now i cant able to book that room in another date, the exception massage came whenever i try to book that room for another date. i changed your code as like "overlaping_bookings = self.search([('room_id', '=', self.room_id.id),('start', '=', self.start),])" is it done in correct way or not , @Ludwik

Comment: Yes. My version compared whole date ranges and threw error if they overlap in any way, you version throws error if start dates are the same.

Comment: anyway thanks Ludwic , but still i cant able to find my solution, i was tried many ways, by constraints,by sql constraints , but still its not completed.

Comment: You need to be more precise about the problem you are having with the solution above.

Comment: what is the need of  1. @api.one 
2.@api.constrains('start', 'end', 'room_id') ???

Comment: What do you mean? Those are just two lines from the solution.

Comment: Actually i want to know that why we are using that? i got the solution thanks ludwik..

Comment: This is the syntax for defining constraints in Odoo 8. Here is [the documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html#openerp.api.constrains).
To be honest I'm confused to whether my post helped or not. If it did you may want to accept it as the solution.

Comment: you given me the right direction Ludwik, from your solution i was thik about to solve that solution in another way, at last i got it. Thanks ludwik

Comment: Sure. Happy I was able to steer you in the right direction :)